# Cell select based on InputBox

Tags: vba, excel

I have an InputBox where the user enters a cell value. Based on the input I need Excel to jump to that cell.

I have this code but it doesn't do what I need.

```
Dim myValue As Variant

myValue = InputBox("IF Week 1, insert W3, if Week 2 insert S3, if week 3 insert O3 or if Week 4 insert K3")

Sheets("Global").Select

Range("myValue").Select

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: Range.(myValue).select ? No quotes? Also if you're just selecting the cell, you don't need the whole selection.pastespecial line.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention that once vba goes to the cell, it copy paste some data. Why the qoutes? i didnt know better:(. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myValue = InputBox("IF Week 1, insert W3, if Week 2 insert S3, if week 3 insert O3 or if Week 4 insert K3")
Sheets("Global").Select 
Range(myValue).Select
```

Comment: it worked perfect. next time i know not to " " . thanks.

Comment: No problem! You would use quotes if you were trying to refer to a named cell. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4D0F13AC-53B7-422E-AFD2-ABD7FF379C64